# How to populate the image in Fresco SimpleDraweeView by setting width and height dynamically?

Tags: android, fresco

> I want to show the image in Fresco SimpleDraweeView and image is coming from the API and with image width and height so i want to set the image with and height dynamically and also i want to show svg image.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `ControllerListener` when the image is requested.

The `onFinalImageSet` method contains `ImageInfo`, which has the image dimensions:

```
ControllerListener controllerListener =
      new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onFinalImageSet(
            String id, @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo, @Nullable Animatable anim) {
          if (imageInfo != null) {
            int w = imageInfo.getWidth();
            int h = imageInfo.getHeight();
            // Use these image dimensions to do whatever you want
          }
        }
      };
```